# Web developing using imac pro 5k screen

Tags: macos, google-chrome, web, retina-display

I set a media query to fire between 992px and 1200 px.

I monitor the screen width using Chrome developer tools.

But the query fires between 793px and 959px.

I have experimented with media queries "min resolution" etc.

But cannot work out how ensure that id #deh4 changes to red when the screen width is precisely between 992px and 1200px.

The current media query code is:

```css
  @media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3) and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3) and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 180dpi) and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px)
    {
      #deh4 {
        color:red;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please share your media query code

Comment: Thanks @gbalduzzi should have include it.